# Recommendation for subset of users using Pyspark mllib ALS/MatrixFactorizationModel

Tags: python, pyspark, distribution, apache-spark-mllib, matrix-factorization

I have built a model using the below code:

```
from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import ALS, MatrixFactorizationModel, Rating

model1 = ALS.train(ratings=ratingsR, rank=model_params['rank'], \
                   iterations=model_params['iterations'], lambda_=model_params['lambda'], \
                   blocks=model_params['blocks'], nonnegative=model_params['nonnegative'], \
                   seed=model_params['seed'])
```

Now I want to predict campaigns for all users (or a subset of users) using distributed environment provided by spark.

I tried `recommendProductsForUsers` which is taking ages to get me 32M Users X 4000 Products.

```
preds = model1.recommendProductsForUsers(num=4000)
```

I really don't need recommendations for all 32M users. I am fine with 100k-200k users as well.

So to modify my process, I tried the spark udf way to process for each user one by one, but using distribution mechanism of spark cluster:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
def udf_preds(sameModel):
    return F.udf(lambda x: get_predictions(x, sameModel))

def get_predictions(x, sameModel):
    preds = sameModel.recommendProducts(user=x, num=4000) # per user it takes around 4s
    return preds

test.withColumn('predictions', udf_preds(model1)(F.col('user_id')))
```

Test contains around 200,000 users. 
The above fails with the following error:

> PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

How to perform the recommendations for a subset of users better?

(EDIT)

From @piscall's response. I tried to do the same using an RDD.

```
preds_rdd = test.rdd.map(lambda x: (x.user_id, sameModel.recommendProducts(x.user_id, 4000)))
preds_rdd.take(2)
```

```
 File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/context.py", line 330, in __getnewargs__
    "It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast "
 Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

 PicklingErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-e114800a26e7> in <module>()
----> 1 preds_rdd.take(2)

 /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/rdd.py in take(self, num)
   1356 
   1357             p = range(partsScanned, min(partsScanned + numPartsToTry, totalParts))
-> 1358             res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
   1359 
   1360             items += res

 /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/context.py in runJob(self, rdd, partitionFunc, partitions, allowLocal)
   1038         # SparkContext#runJob.
   1039         mappedRDD = rdd.mapPartitions(partitionFunc)
-> 1040         sock_info = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
   1041         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, mappedRDD._jrdd_deserializer))
   1042 

 /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/rdd.py in _jrdd(self)
   2470 
   2471         wrapped_func = _wrap_function(self.ctx, self.func, self._prev_jrdd_deserializer,
-> 2472                                       self._jrdd_deserializer, profiler)
   2473         python_rdd = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD(self._prev_jrdd.rdd(), wrapped_func,
   2474                                              self.preservesPartitioning)

 /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/rdd.py in _wrap_function(sc, func, deserializer, serializer, profiler)
   2403     assert serializer, "serializer should not be empty"
   2404     command = (func, profiler, deserializer, serializer)
-> 2405     pickled_command, broadcast_vars, env, includes = _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)
   2406     return sc._jvm.PythonFunction(bytearray(pickled_command), env, includes, sc.pythonExec,
   2407                                   sc.pythonVer, broadcast_vars, sc._javaAccumulator)

 /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/rdd.py in _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)
   2389     # the serialized command will be compressed by broadcast
   2390     ser = CloudPickleSerializer()
-> 2391     pickled_command = ser.dumps(command)
   2392     if len(pickled_command) > (1 << 20):  # 1M
   2393         # The broadcast will have same life cycle as created PythonRDD

 /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/serializers.py in dumps(self, obj)
    573 
    574     def dumps(self, obj):
--> 575         return cloudpickle.dumps(obj, 2)
    576 
    577 

 /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py in dumps(obj, protocol)
    916 
    917     cp = CloudPickler(file,protocol)
--> 918     cp.dump(obj)
    919 
    920     return file.getvalue()

/u
I have built a model using the below code:

from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import ALS, MatrixFactorizationModel, Rating
sr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py in dump(self, obj)
    247                 msg = "Could not serialize object: %s: %s" % (e.__class__.__name__, emsg)
    248             print_exec(sys.stderr)
--> 249             raise pickle.PicklingError(msg)
    250 
    251 

PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

Comment: Can you show the entire stack-trace?

Comment: The stack does not show anything but lines of places of error, and `test.withColumn('predictions', udf_preds(sameModel)(F.col('user_id')))` here it goes pickling error. From what i read, this is because sameModel (model object has SC with it) so that cannot be serialised.

Comment: Please post get_predictions function

Comment: Do you mean: def get_predictions(x, sameModel):
    preds = sameModel.recommendProducts(user=x, num=4000) # per user it takes around 4s
    return preds

Comment: Will need more information I guess. What object is `sameModel`? Is it the `ALS` instance? I don't know if you can pass an ML model into a `UDF` but I can't see a broadcast variable either. What do you think of taking an `RDD` approach? I have something in mind that I think can help

Comment: sameModel is model1, I am updating the question to avoid confusion. Yes, it is an ALS instance. I would like to broadcast the model object, since for every row in  validation, I want to call `recommendProduct` method.

Comment: Please check out the answer and let me know if you get any errors with it

Comment: @AnkitaMehta, A question: you want to predict rating of users on each of 4000 products, or you want to find top-4000 products for each user from your model tank which might contains 100K products?

Comment: @jxc: I want to predict ratings on all 4000 products.

Comment: Seems I would raise an issue with the mllib als github repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what I would do is to use [predictAll](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel.predictAll) method. Assume that *df_products* is a dataframe containing all 4,000 products and *df_users* a dataframe with the 100-200K selected users, then do a crossJoin to find all combination of two data sets to form the testdata, then use predictAll which will yield Rating objects of selected users over the 4000 products:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast
from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import ALS, MatrixFactorizationModel, Rating

testdata = broadcast(df_products).crossJoin(df_users).select('user', 'product').rdd.map(tuple)

model.predictAll(testdata).collect()
```

Use the example from the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html#examples) which has 4 products(1,2,3,4) and 4 users (1,2,3,4):

```
df_products.collect()                                                                                              
# [Row(product=1), Row(product=3), Row(product=2), Row(product=4)]

# a subset of all users:
df_users.collect()                                                                                                 
# [Row(user=1), Row(user=3)]

testdata.collect()                                                                                                 
# [(1, 1), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 4), (3, 1), (3, 3), (3, 2), (3, 4)]

model.predictAll(testdata).collect()
#[Rating(user=1, product=4, rating=0.9999459747142155),
# Rating(user=3, product=4, rating=4.99555263974573),
# Rating(user=1, product=1, rating=4.996821463543848),
# Rating(user=3, product=1, rating=1.000199620693615),
# Rating(user=1, product=3, rating=4.996821463543848),
# Rating(user=3, product=3, rating=1.000199620693615),
# Rating(user=1, product=2, rating=0.9999459747142155),
# Rating(user=3, product=2, rating=4.99555263974573)]
```

**Note:** you might want to screen out users which are not in the existing model before creating `testdata` and process them separately.

Comment: Hi @jxc, So ultimately, I did this itself. Created an rdd of user (in validation set) with every campaign and used predictAll method. However, it is extremely slow. :( But at least something to solve the issue.

Comment: @AnkitaMehta understood! as the testdata will contain from 400-800m records, that's a very big list. but if you want to do it in a fixed user list and a fixed product list, I think there is probably not better way to handle this task. :( IMO, for general recommendation systems, top-100 should be enough for most of the tasks. 4000 is just too big.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```py
"""
Convert the test df to rdd, and then map a function that returns 
(user_id, array(Rating(user, product, rating)))
"""
preds_rdd = test.rdd.map(lambda x: (x.user_id, sameModel.recommendProducts(x.user_id, 4000)))

# Convert (user_id, array(Rating(user, product, rating))) to 
# (user_id, array(product_names))
preds_rdd2 = preds_rdd.map(lambda row: row[0], [x.product for x in row[1])
# Convert above RDD to DF with user_id and predicted_products columns
preds_df = preds_rdd2.toDF(["user_id", "predicted_products"])
```

I have not tested but it's straight from the documentation over [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#module-pyspark.mllib.recommendation):

You can then choose to join it back to the original dataframe, or retain columns.

You can then explode the array of products into different rows with `explode()` if you need.

Comment: So the issue remains the same. `sameModel` or model object cannot be serialized. Adding full stack trace in answer.

Comment: @AnkitaMehta can you try if it is working correctly for one user?

Comment: so for one user it is `sameModel.recommendProducts(singleUser, 4000)` works like a charm. The reason is sameModel is not sent for operation in distribution. I guess you are seeing this incorrect.

Comment: @AnkitaMehta No I'm understanding what's happening. Will try to work on it with samples.

Answer (score 1):

what about `preds = sameModel.predict(x)`, I don't know spark and even scala, but that is how we do in python and i guess it's same for spark. If you want to predict with sub samples of x then you can do something like: `preds = sameModel.predict(x[0:200,::])` or vise verse for the columns.

Comment: The same is done via `sameModel.recommendProducts(user=x, num=4000)`. Ordered recommendation and its predicted rating is what we are looking for. And spark data frame cannot be used on splits (like lists) as it is not sequential, but distributed.